# css spin on hover of container

Tags: css, hover, containers

I looking to have i.spin animate when you hover on the container div.logo

HTML

```css
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.spin:hover {
  animation: spin 450ms;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <i class="fa fa-envelope-o spin" aria-hidden="true"></i> D<span>e</span>trevnoc
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

Instead of watching for hover on the `icon` which is small, put the hover on the parent with class `icon` and add the hover animation to spin. Refer the below CSS.

```
.logo:hover > .spin {
  animation: spin 450ms;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

```css
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
.logo:hover > .spin {
  animation: spin 450ms;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="logo">
  <i class="fa fa-envelope-o spin" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span>De</span>trevnoc
</div>
```

Comment: That is exactly it! ".logo:hover > .spin {" is what I was looking for.